# What is a good handwriting recognition software?

Tags: conversion, ocr, handwriting

I bought a [Livescribe pen](http://www.livescribe.com/) which records whatever I write (and say).

However, it can only give me pdf versions of what I wrote. Using [MyScript](http://www.visionobjects.com/handwriting_recognition/pulse/pulse.htm#windows) (an paid extension) I can have it convert my handwritten notes to digital text.

But it turns out it doesn't like Dutch very much and isn't working perfect.

So my question is: does anyone know of a handwriting recognition software that can convert my pdf files to digital text?

Preferably free and for Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: BTW any solution that works on scanned, handwritten documents is welcome too

Comment: You should add a "OCR" tag to this question.

Comment: There you go! ;-)

Comment: I tried some of the softwares mentioned on Wikipedia, but none of them were able to create a readable sentence.

Comment: I suggest you contact MyScript's support and send them samples of your Dutch handwriting which are badly recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with these applications, but you can take a look at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition#OCR_software) and try out some of them.

Comment: I tried the OCR softwares, but none of them worked for me sadly. But it was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)):

> It was originally developed as
>   proprietary software at
>   Hewlett-Packard between 1985 until
>   1995. After ten years without any development taking place, Hewlett
>   Packard and UNLV released it as open
>   source in 2005. Tesseract is currently
>   developed by Google and released under
>   the Apache License, Version 2.0.
>
> Tesseract is considered one of the
>   most accurate free software OCR
>   engines currently available

The drawback is that it only processes tiff file, maybe you can use other convertor to convert pdf to tiff and let Tesseract does the job.

Comment: I find that gimagereader does I good job as a GUI for tesseract. link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimagereader/

Answer (score 0):

Handwriting is very hard to convert after the fact, there is a digital ink format that captures the time related portion of the info, which makes it doable.  Good luck, write in English (larger and thus more money spent on development)? It is a hard problem.